# Infinity loop in while statement

Tags: c

Here is a snippet from my code

```
scanf("%d", &s);

while(s!=1 && s!=2) {
    if(scanf("%d", &s) != 1) {
        show_warning(); //just print some info msg
    }
}
```

The idea is to execute show_warning function only if user enter something different of 1,2 and entered value to be only integer.
With the code above it jumps in infinity loop. How to fix that ?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of s and show_warning?

Comment: the scanf in the loop will return how many tokens were read and not the value that was entered.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: If you don't enter a number and the `scanf` fails, then you go into an infinite loop. @CashCow: It think the OP is aware of that.

Comment: This is a classic illustration of why `scanf()` is hard to use.  It is often easier to control the error handling and improve the error reporting if you use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the failed input operation doesn't extract any characters from the stream (and you'll keep reading the invalid input over and over), so you have to empty the input manually. For example:

```
char buf[1000];

// ...

if(scanf("%d", &s) != 1)
{
    puts("Error, try again: ");
    fgets(buf, 1000, stdin);
}
```

As I suggested in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808101/596781), if you use `fgets` from the start to always read one line and process it later, you overcome this problem.

(The same philosophy is true in C++: read the whole line first so the input stream can move on, and process the line later to see if its valid.)

Comment: Or `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` which consumes indefinitely long lines, whereas the `fgets()` only consumes unreasonably long lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: True. My C IO isn't quite as eloquent as I might like it to be... that said, above construction will also loop and consume as much as necessary, only it'll print the message every so many characters.

Comment: I was proposing the loop in place of the `fgets()` call, so yours will report every so many characters of an extremely overlong line, whereas the alternative would report once per line.  For the most part the difference is irrelevant. 1 KiB is big enough that people have problems entering that length of line manually (my terminal doesn't allow that many characters to be buffered).  It matters for file-based input, in theory.

Comment: Actually there's a subtle difference: If the 1001st character is 1 or 2, then my construction succeeds spuriously, whereas yours correctly consumes the entire line!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a while loop?  Do you want show_warning(); to be called once, or repeatedly?  If you answered once then you only need an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Also what happens when no `scanf` succeeded? The variable `s` remains unchanged (and perhaps with an undefined value, if you did not initialize it). You should set it, or change the condition of the `while` !

And you really should learn to compile with warnings enabled and debugging information (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux)

Comment: No, the `&&` is correct. This is the classic problem of invalid input not being consumed.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it is looping until infinity?

You only get the warning message when you have not entered a number because it did not read a token.

Changing the && to || though is a certain way to ensure it will run to infinity as your loop will never break then.

You might want an alternative message to prompt the user to enter data when they did enter a number but not 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're having issues when a non-integer is input. This is because `scanf` leaves non-matching characters in the buffer, so subsequent calls are seeing the same input and looping.

What you need to do is if the `scanf` call returns any number other 1 is: read that character in using `scanf("%c",&somechar)` so you can print it and tell the user that it isn't accepted. The non-accepted input will then have been removed so the next call to `scanf` will give you the next input rather than the one you saw on the previous iteration.