# while loop dependent upon a scanf result is ending prematurely

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm writing a simple program in C to calculate grades and grade averages.  I feed it a textfile from the command line via the "< xyz.txt" and output to another text via "> xyz_output.txt" commands.  There are over 100 lines of data in the input file, but the program keeps exiting the loop around line 6 of the input for some reason... I've checked the input format several times and I can't seem to figure out why it's exiting prematurely.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char pp[4];
    char school[3];
    int class;
    int student;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;
    int q;
    int r;
    float average;
    int runtotal;
    int grouptotal = 0;
    float groupaverage;
    int counter = 0;
    while (scanf("%3s%2s%2i%2i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", pp, school, &class, &student, &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h, &i, &j, &k, &l, &m, &n, &o, &p, &q, &r) == 22)
    {
        runtotal = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r);
        average = (float)runtotal / 18;
        grouptotal = grouptotal + runtotal;
        counter++;
        printf ("%i.\n", counter);
        printf ("%s%s-%i-%i -- %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i %1i\n", pp, school, class, student, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r);
        printf ("Total score: %i\n", runtotal);
        printf ("Average: %f\n", average);
        printf ("Running Total: %i\n\n", grouptotal);
    }
    groupaverage = (float)grouptotal / counter;
    printf ("Calculations complete.\nThe total score for this group was %i.\nThe average score for this group was %f.\n", grouptotal, groupaverage);
    return 0;
}
```

and here are the first 10 lines of the actual input .txt file.

```
preKO6101 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 2 0
preHI6114 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 1
preHI5116 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0
preHI6103 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
preHI5132 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
preHI5109 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1
preHI6113 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
preSA5116 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 0 2 2
preHI6109 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
preHI5107 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

It seems to make it to 'preHI5109' but then exits.  I have a feeling that it has to do with how I'm using scanf, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: what is the number returned by `scanf`? You could store it somewhere.... And what is `errno`? and `ferror(stdin)` ? Compile with debugging information and all warnings (e.g. `gcc -g -Wall`) and use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). And what is your operating system and your compiler? Perhaps using the `%n` format control could help.

Comment: I'll try storing the return real quick and get back to you.  There isn't any error, the program simply exits the loop and goes the the line right after it to do the final calculation.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808156/841108)

Comment: Unless this an exercise to learn C, there is no reason to use C for this.

Comment: As suggested by @Basile , knowing the `scanf()` result will help.  Further: `(scanf("%3s%2s%2i%2i %i %i %i %i ...` is the same as `(scanf("%3s%2s%2i%2i%i%i%i%i ...`.  The spaces before `"%i"` may be useful for review, but do not affect `scanf()` functionality as `"%i"` consumes leading spaces anyways. Suggest reading the lines with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` to parse.  Certainly some stray `char` is lurking/missing in the data file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: what other languages are you suggesting? Ocaml? And it looks like a homework in C.

Comment: @Basile awk or perl would be appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method employed to read the data file is very sensitive to mis-alignment, parsing and I/O issues.  Suggest more robust IO and parsing as certainly some small error exist in the data file.  Use `fgets()` to control reading the line orientated data.

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  int count = sscanf(buf, "%3s%2s%2i%2i %i %i %i %i /* ... */ %i %i", 
    pp, school, &class, &student, &a, &b, &c, /* ... */  &q, &r);
  if (count != 22) {
    printf("Error %d (TBD relevant text)\n", count);
    break;
  }
  /* continue with normal processing */
}
```

Other improvements
  `int a[18]` instead of `int a; int b; ...`
  Use loops to then scan, sum, print the 18 elements.
  Use `"%i"` rather than `"%1i"`.  The `1` is the *minimum width*, so why have it?

Note: If the input file was supplied by a Prof., It would not surprise me that something intentionally bad is in it.  The lesson: do not trust data input unless well vetted.  User input is evil.

Comment: thanks chux, your code worked (the count just needed to be 22, not 23) I ran it on the input file and it processed all 100 lines of data.

Comment: Just for learning purposes though, I'm curious about why scanf was "seeing" or not "seeing" characters that caused it to malfunction?  When viewing the input data with the naked eye, I couldn't find anything wrong with it, so what was scanf seeing that I wasn't?

Comment: @Jason Sturgeon  (23 to 22 fixed)  By using `fgets()` to read 1 line at a time, one benefits at error localization.  The text file was certainly line orientated.  Let's say a line had extra `char`s at the end `"              z"`.  The `fgets()` will read the line (up to 100) and the `sscanf()` will scan successfully, ignoring the extra junk, merrily going on to the next line.  Your original code would try to read that `z` as `pp` and this will lead to doom. eventually an `%i` will try to scan letters fail and progress not further.  But things are a bit lost where the original problem occurred.

Comment: @Jason Sturgeon BTW: to _improve_, use a `sscanf()` tool: `int ch; sscanf(buf, "%3s%2s%2i ... %i %i %c"`. By appending a `" %c"` and not increasing the 22 to 23, you have created sentential.  Any non-white-space after the last expected `int` gets detected.  (I had 1/2 implemented this in my original answer.)

Comment: Again, thanks chux.  I'm actually a linguistics professor, so programming is pretty far from my forte, but I've been dabbling in C mainly because I hear that most other languages are based off of C and that if you can write code in C, you make transitioning to other languages much, much easier.  Using it to sort out the simple mathematics of some research seemed like a good starting point and a way to save myself hours of time in the future.  Thanks for humoring my questions.  I'll let you pros get back to it then.

Comment: PS, I couldn't help but chuckle at the comment you left earlier, the input file was indeed supplied by a prof, but I was the prof!

Comment: @Jason Sturgeon Profs [are not bad, they are just drawn that way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Who_Framed_Roger_Rabbit_characters#Jessica_Rabbit).